# Is valgrind not finding memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

This code creates a BST, fills it, and makes an effort to release resources. Two versions of release() are shown below:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int d;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;


int main() {

    Node **tree = NULL;

    tree = mkTree();
    if (!tree) {
        puts("problem\n");
        return 1;
    }

    insert(7, tree);
    insert(3, tree);
    insert(9, tree);
    insert(6, tree);

    printTree(*tree);
    release(tree);
    free(tree);

    return 0;

}
/* Make a new binary tree */
    Node **mkTree() {

    Node **t = malloc(sizeof **t);
    return t;
}

/* insert datum d into tree */


bool insert(int d, Node **tree) {

    Node *newptr = NULL;

    if (tree == NULL) { /*ptr to rootptr NULL */
        return false;
    }

    if (*tree == NULL) {
        newptr = buildNode(d);
        if (!newptr) {
            return false;
        }
        *tree = newptr;
        return true;
    }

    return insert(d, d < (*tree)->d ? &(*tree)->left : &(*tree)->right);
}
```

What I don't understand is why valgrind claims all resources are freed in BOTH cases (I and II) below. I try to clear each node using release(), and, at the end of main, I call free(tree) to clear Node **tree, which is declared in main.

I.

```
/* release resources by passing Node **tree */

void release(Node **tree) {

    if (*tree) {
        Node *here = *tree;
        release(&here->left);
        release(&here->right);
    }
    free(*tree);

}
```

II.

```
/* passing Node *tree. this shouldn't free anything, right? */

void release(Node *tree) {

    if (tree) {
        Node *here = tree;
        release(here->left);
        release(here->right);
    }
    free(tree);

}
```

Despite the choice, running this program with four insertions gives

```
==5182== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5182==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5182==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 60 bytes allocated
```

What's happening here? Is valgrind just keeping a tally count of the number of malloc's and free's?

Comment: I can tell you that valgrind is most certainly not just keeping a tally count of the number of `malloc`s and `free`s. Can you show us your main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of `Release` are doing the same thing.  One just has an extra (and unnecessary) level of indirection.  You can pass a pointer to a function and free that pointer; it is not necessary to pass the address of the variable holding the pointer.

In fact, the call to `free` does exactly that.  It just accepts the pointer value (not the address of the variable holding the pointer).

Comment: Thanks! My knowledge seems to be rather fragile at this point.

Comment: @user1505713: A pointer's value is an address.  Copy it as many times as you wish, the value won't change.  It's that value that `free` needs to do its job.  The pointer variable itself is a different matter, just as an `int` has a value as well as an address (where it is actually stored).